# Why do particle resonances lead to peaks in the cross section?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, singularities, greens-functions, scattering-cross-section, s-matrix-theory

Since bound states lead to poles in Green functions, I wonder if this is the reason for peaks in the cross section.

From a QFT point of view, the infinitesimal cross section $\text d\sigma/\text d\Omega$ is proportional to the absolute square of the sum over all Feynman diagrams. So for a certain energy near the mass of a bound state, the divergence in the Green function should carry over to the Feynman diagram and thus to the cross section.

Is this correct?

Comment: $\uparrow$ Yes.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform How can I mark this question as answered?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is **Yes**. A standard reference is Weinberg's QFT, Vol.1, chapter 10.